# Mismatch in Python numpy.testing

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any chance for storing the value os mismatch in one variable?

```
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(x,y,decimal=2)
```

As you see the ouput of the function is a boolean and an assertion error.
The mismatch value appears within the message

```
AssertionError: 

Arrays are not almost equal to 2 decimals

(mismatch 57.095709571%)


x: array([ 0.01,  0.01,  0.01, ..., -0.  ,  0.01,  0.01])
y: array([0.02, 0.02, 0.02, ..., 0.02, 0.02, 0.02])
```

Comment: Hi @UserStack, welcome to SO! Could you please add your code and also more information about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
        try:
            np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(x,y,decimal=2)
        except AssertionError as e:
            mismatch = e.args[0].split('\n')[3].split(' ')[1][:-2]
```

then mismatch will contain an str with the value you are looking for.
In your example:

```
 mismatch = 57.095709571
```